# Sample mean vs population mean

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, mean

I was provided with the following:
$X_1,\ldots,X_5$ are independent random samples from a distribution with mean $5$ and standard deviation $3$. Then I was asked to find the mean and standard deviation of $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{5}\sum_{i=1}^5X_i$.

Where I am at so far, the mean is still 5, and then to get the sd in it the original sd squared divided by n [and then the square root of that]. Or in other words, $\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}}$

I got 1.341641 
Am I even close?

Comment: you're correct.